# I have multiIndexes for my dataframe, how do I calculate the sum for one level?

Tags: python, dataframe

[image: my dataframe]

Hi everyone, I want to calculate the sum of `Violent_type` count according to `year`. For example, calculating total count of `violent_type` for year `2013`, which is `18728+121662+1035`. But I don't know how to select the data when there are multiIndexes. Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `level` argument in [pandas.DataFrame.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is what you are looking for.

> **level**  int, level name, or sequence of such, default None
>
> If the axis is a MultiIndex (hierarchical), group by a particular level or levels.

To answer your question, you only need:

```py
df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum()
# or
df.groupby(level=['district', 'year']).sum()
```

To see the effect

```py
import pandas as pd

iterables = [['001', 'SST'], [2013, 2014], ['Dangerous', 'Non-Violent', 'Violent']]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['district', 'year', 'Violent_type'])

df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(0, len(index))), index=index, columns=['count'])

'''
print(df)

                            count
district year Violent_type       
001      2013 Dangerous         0
              Non-Violent       1
              Violent           2
         2014 Dangerous         3
              Non-Violent       4
              Violent           5
SST      2013 Dangerous         6
              Non-Violent       7
              Violent           8
         2014 Dangerous         9
              Non-Violent      10
              Violent          11
'''

print(df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum())

'''
               count
district year       
001      2013      3
         2014     12
SST      2013     21
         2014     30
'''

print(df.groupby(level=['district', 'year']).sum())

'''
               count
district year       
001      2013      3
         2014     12
SST      2013     21
         2014     30
'''
```

Comment: Thank you for your help sir. I have another question that how do I calculate the percentage of each violent_type based on district and year? I tried to df['count']/df.groupby(level=['district','year']).sum() but got an error saying they have different indexes.

Comment: @MaverickSauce `df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(lambda x: x / x['count'].sum())`.